# Converting to Integer in PHP

Tags: php, type-conversion

Why in PHP language, the code below prints `7` ?

`print (int) ((0.1+0.7) * 10)`

While

`print (int) ((0.1+0.8) * 10)`

prints `9` ?

Comment: Because a `int` conversion just strips the decimals and floating point math isn't precise. You could use `round` instead

Answer (score 0):

You need to use round() function while converting float values

```
print (int) round((0.1+0.7) * 10);
```

Comment: You don't *need* to. It depends on what the goal is.